# Describe the Jordan form of a linear operator $T:\mathbb{R}^7\to\mathbb{R}^7$ with characteristic polynomial $p_T(t)=(t-1)^2(t-2)^4(t-3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

> Describe the Jordan form of a linear operator $T:\mathbb{R}^7\to\mathbb{R}^7$ with characteristic polynomial $$p_T(t)=(t-1)^2(t-2)^4(t-3)$$ and such as $\dim(\ker(T-2I))=2, \dim(\ker(T-I))=1$ and $\ker(T-2I)^3\neq\ker(T-2I)^2$

---

My attempt:

As we have the characteristic polynomial and the dimension of the subspespaces associated to the eigenvalues, then I can say that the Jordan form to the operator is

\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
1 & 1 &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  & 2 &  &  &  &  \\
 &  & 1 & 2 &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  & 2 &  &  \\
 &  &  &  & 1 & 2 &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Is this correct?

I don't understand the condition $\ker(T-2I)^3\neq\ker(T-2I)^2$, what does it means and what is the purpose of that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The Jordan blocks associated with eigenvalues $1$ and $3$ are correct.  To deduce the correct Jordan block associated with eigenvalue $2$, first note that $\dim(\ker(T - 2I)) = 2$ implies that there are two possibilities below:
\begin{align*}
& \text{(a).}\; J_a = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}, \quad 
\text{(b).}\; J_b = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}. 
\end{align*}
It is easy to verify that
\begin{align*}
(J_a - 2I_{(4)})^2 = (J_a - 2I_{(4)})^3 = 0, 
\end{align*}
while
\begin{align*}
(J_b - 2I_{(4)})^2 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \neq 0 = (J_b - 2I_{(4)})^3.
\end{align*}

Therefore, case (a) contradicts with the condition $\ker((T - 2I)^2) \neq \ker((T - 2I)^3)$, implying that case (b) is the unique compatible Jordan block.